# foreach $_POST using jquery-php ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
<textarea id="ap1" rows="1"></textarea>
<textarea id="ap2" rows="1"></textarea>
```

js

```
var ap1 = $('#ap1').val();
var ap2 = $('#ap2').val();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "ajax.php",
    data: {ap1:ap1, ap2:ap2},
    success: function (data) {
    $("#info").html(data).slideDown("slow");
    }
});
```

ajax.php

```
$msg = "sky";
foreach($_POST as $item){
    if ($item == "") {$msg = "sea"}
};
echo json_encode($msg);
```

In fact, I have much more textareas, but here are only two of them, just for example.

Something is wrong, because, if some textarea is empty, `success` function doesn`t work, i.e. nothing happens as response.

Comment: set dataType as text and  try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `empty()` instead of `==`

```
$msg = "sky";
foreach($_POST as $item){
   if (empty($item)) {$msg = "sea"}
};
echo json_encode($msg);
```

Answer (score 2):

Send text area values which have data not empty ones. It can be done just by if else statement

Answer (score 1):

I got a parse error on this line :

```
if ($item == "") {$msg = "sea"}
```

Add semicolon, i guess

```
if ($item == "") {$msg = "sea";}
```